# C# unable to resolve service for type context

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I'm using API to implement some services.

I get an error :

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Zipcode_Service.Models.IZipcodeRepository' while attempting to activate 'Zipcode_Service.Controllers.CityController'.

The constructor of my cotroller or the deceleration of the _repository is causing the issue :

```
    private IZipcodeRepository _repository;
    public CityController(ILogger<CityController> logger, IZipcodeRepository repository)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _repository = repository;
    }
```

My interface :

```
public interface IZipcodeRepository
{
    IEnumerable<City> GetCitiesByCityName(string cityName);
  //  City GetCityNameById(int cityId);
}
```

My ZipcodeRepository :

```
public class ZipcodeRepository : IZipcodeRepository
{
    private ZipcodeContext _context;
    private ILogger<ZipcodeRepository> _logger;

    public ZipcodeRepository(ZipcodeContext context, ILogger<ZipcodeRepository> logger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IEnumerable<City> GetCitiesByCityName(string cityName)
    {
       return _context.Cities.Where(t => t.Name.Contains(cityName)).ToList();
    }
```

I saw many similar question, most of them suggested the problem was in the controller using the repository and not the interface. This is not the case.

**EDIT: Some more info**
 My startup page:

```
  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        _config = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<ZipcodeContext>();
        services.AddScoped<IZipcodeRepository, ZipcodeRepository>();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
    ...
        app.UseMvc(config =>
        {
            config.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
                );
```

My context class :

```
    public ZipcodeContext(IConfigurationRoot config, DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Zipcode> Zipcodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Street> Streets { get; set; }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:ZipcodeContextConnection"]);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using any specific IoC container?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, what is it :D @VijayanathViswanathan ? I use `            services.AddScoped<IZipcodeRepository, ZipcodeRepository>();` in configureServices if that's what you meant.

Comment: Can you please show us your `Startup.cs` file? Specifically where you register your services.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Edited, please have a look .

Answer (score 2):

The issue is usually associated with an error while the container is trying to resolve the object graph to satisfy dependencies.

In the comments you indicated that you registered `IZipcodeRepository`

```
services.AddScoped<IZipcodeRepository, ZipcodeRepository>();
```

Great. But that error can also happen while trying to initialize the implementation `ZipcodeRepository` or one of it's dependencies. For example if `ZipcodeContext` threw an exception while being initialized it would cause the same issue.

Make sure that the context is also configured properly.

For example

```
services.AddDbContext<ZipcodeContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionNameHere")));
```

Comment: I edited my question and added the startup page content. I already used `useSqlServer()` inside the context class, do I need to use it again in configureServices ? Anyway even when I tried to use `            services.AddDbContext<ZipcodeContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("ZipcodeContextConnection")));` it didn't work ..

Comment: @sagi Did applying the fix from the other question with the `IConfigurationRoot` issue help resolve this one?

Comment: @sagi no if you already have it in the context then there is no need to do it in startup. I couldn't tell based on the code provided at the time so made an assumption.

Comment: Yes it did :) I'll upvote for the effort and because it can help someone else

Comment: @sagi so it was related to a config issue associated the creation of the object graph

Comment: Regardless, I have a question, and I'm locked from asking new one haha . If you can help - The service works, but only in english . When I pass cityName in hebrew, it recognize the string is different letters(from the same launguage, like if I pass "A" in debug I see "F")